# Oracle SQL, get varchar2 column with greater length in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, string-length, varchar2

I have a varchar2(8) column in a table, and I want to convert it to varchar2(100) *in the select statement* (i.e. I don't want to to call an "alter table" afterwards).*
Is it possible? Is there some function like "to_varchar2(x, 100)"?

(*) the reason is that I need to use the column in a "model" statement, where there will be additional identifiers that are longer. I don't want to create an intermediate table and use "alter table" to change the varchar2 length.
Example:

```
  select date, mystringvariable r, somenumber v from MyTable
  model
  unique single reference
  return updated rows   
  partition by(date) dimension by(r) measures(v)
  rules upsert automatic order ( 
  v['too_long_identifier']  = v['X1']
  );

     Error at line 5:

     ORA-12899: value too large for column ??? (actual: 19, maximum: 8)
          partition by(date) dimension by(r) measures(v)
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where in your query you need to do this (I don't have your data to test), but if `str` is any expression of data type `varchar2(8)` and you need to recast it as `varchar2(100)`, you can use the `cast` function:

```
 .... cast(str as varchar2(100)) ....
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.